# Append text to the beginning of a distribution group display name in Active Directory

Tags: powershell

I would like to append a suffix to the display name in an Active Directory distribution group. So right now I have two groups called "Developers" and "Testers" and would like to rename them to "Seattle_Developers" and "Seattle_Testers" respectively.

Complete AD and powershell newbie

What I've done so far is:

```
    #Returns all the Distribution Groups found in the specified 
    #relational distinguished name
    $groups=Get-ADGroup -Filter {GroupCategory -eq 'Distribution'} - 
    searchbase "OU=Distribution Groups,OU=Groups,DC=techno,DC=com" - 
    Properties Members

    foreach ($group in $groups)
    {
    $group.name
    }
```

However I'm not sure how to go trough the two objects inside the OU and update the names.

Thanks for the help.

I expect the names of the objects to be changed by adding a prefix to the current display name.

Answer (score 1):

This will be a multi-step process since one command can't perform a complete rename. This assumes you want to change `Name`,`DisplayName`, and `SamAccountName`.

```
foreach ($group in $groups)
{
    $newName = "Seattle_{0}" -f $group.name
    $group | Set-ADGroup -DisplayName $newName -SamAccountName $newName -Passthru |
        Rename-ADObject -NewName $newName
}
```

`$newName` stores the desired name created by using the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6#format-operator--f) (`-f`). This makes it easy to reference the new name multiple times in subsequent commands.

[Set-ADGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/set-adgroup?view=win10-ps) is used to modify a number of properties about a group. The `Name` property is not one of them. The [Rename-ADObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/rename-adobject?view=win10-ps) can be used to change `Name` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If want to just rename the group, you should be able to pipe from your `Get-ADGroup` into a `foreach` `Rename-ADObject`:

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter {GroupCategory -eq 'Distribution'} -searchbase "OU=Distribution Groups,OU=Groups,DC=techno,DC=com" -Properties Members | %{Rename-ADObject -Identity $_.DistinguishedName -NewName ("Seattle_" + $_.Name)}
```

This **will not** change the `samaccountname`. For that you might want to include the `Set-ADGroup` cmdlet (AdminOfThings' answer)